# [16.04]Error after login

Tags: login, login-screen

i am using ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10. My first problem was that ubuntu only showed a empty screen after boot. Turning gfxmode in grub to text solved the problem. After that I installed nvidia drivers. Now after the login screen an error box is shown and than again the login screen. Had someone the same problem or how to solve it?

Comment: What error is shown?

Comment: Nothing specific. If i recognize rightly something like this: An internal error was encountered,sorry.